# Xcode compiles and runs only on iPhone 4s and 5 simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I think I've got a pretty weird one here.

So my app runs on the 4s and 5 simulator, but anything above including 5s puts out the below list of errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I went to the "Ignoring file /User/..." and deleted them, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The errors in that image indicate a link issue due to likely not including certain frameworks in your linker build settings phase.  It's also possible that the libraries you are linking against do not contain x86_64 slices (meaning they will work for i386 simulators like the iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 but not x86_64 simulators like the iPhone 5s).